# Java character case changing inconsistency issue

Tags: java

I have this issue: I am supposed to read a text file and for a set of letters if they are in lowercase then I must convert them to uppercase.

Following is the code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        //outputArray[i] = inputToArray[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < charListLength; j++) {

            if (inputToArray[i] == charList[j]) {

                if (Character.isLowerCase(inputToArray[i])) {
                    inputToArray[i] = Character.toUpperCase(inputToArray[i]);
                }
                if (Character.isUpperCase(inputToArray[i])) {
                    inputToArray[i] = Character.toLowerCase(inputToArray[i]);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The input file contains:

a, e, i, o, u lowercase This is a story
A, E, I, O, U UPPERCASE

But the output produces:

a, e, i, o, u lowercase This is a story
a, e, i, o, u uPPeRCaSe

--

Please note that "a, e, i, o, u lowercase This is a story" and "A, E, I, O, U UPPERCASE" are separate lines in the input file and the output file contains them like so as well.

Where am I going wrong please?

Thank you for your great help so please help.

SOLVED:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        //outputArray[i] = inputToArray[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < charListLength; j++) {

            if (inputToArray[i] == charList[j]) {

                if (Character.isLowerCase(inputToArray[i])) {
                    inputToArray[i] = Character.toUpperCase(inputToArray[i]);
                } else if (Character.isUpperCase(inputToArray[i])) {
                    inputToArray[i] = Character.toLowerCase(inputToArray[i]);
                }

                break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Needed the break!

Comment: What is in charList?

Comment: use else-if instead of two if statements

Comment: charList is the array of characters I have to match the input text against.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace your second `if`-clause with `else if`.

Consider this:

Input is `a`. Your first `if` dissolves to `true` and makes `a` uppercase -> `A`.

But then your second `if` also dissolves to `true` because `A` is now uppercase and therefore it gets converted to lowercase again -> `a`.

Fixed version using `else if`
:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    //outputArray[i] = inputToArray[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < charListLength; j++) {

        if (inputToArray[i] == charList[j]) {

            if (Character.isLowerCase(inputToArray[i])) {
                inputToArray[i] = Character.toUpperCase(inputToArray[i]);
            }
            else if (Character.isUpperCase(inputToArray[i])) {
                inputToArray[i] = Character.toLowerCase(inputToArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same result, only the first line is getting modified as provided above. The second line appreas but without the conversion.